# How to open file:/// in Phonegap window.open system browser

Tags: android, cordova

I want to open a file saved in my local system for example: file:/// in a device broswer whe I click on anchor link.

I've tried this:

```
<a href="#" id="examplelink" data-href="file:///mnt/sdcard/documents/third/index.html" class="load-swf">Load SWF1</a>
```

so:

```
$( '#examplelink' ).on('tap', function() {

    var url = $( this ).data( 'href' );

    navigator.app.loadUrl( encodeURI( url ), { openExternal:true });            

});
```

But it doesn't work...

if I try with an url like http://www.google.com.co/ works perfectly.... but using file:/// is not going well...

Comment: For security reasons you can't open local file from an external server. But you can or use as said in an answer the Filesystem api of phonegap or do a custom plugin

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow btw :~)